# ios Singleton Pattern and completion handlers not being called

Tags: ios, singleton

So I have a WebImage class which holds images and image url's. I have an ImageLoader class which is designed to only have one instance. It holds a mutable array of WebImages and basically just loads all the images. But for some reason the recursive method which grabs items from the queue and loads their images stops after loading one image, sometimes before. I suspect it has to do with the singleton pattern and that the object is somehow releasing something prematurely. Some code:

My ImageLoader Class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ConnectionManager *conman;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *queue;
@end
...
+(ImageLoader*)defaultLoader{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static ImageLoader *sharedInstance = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[ImageLoader alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    self.queue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.conman = [[ConnectionManager alloc] init]; //a manager for loading images and whatnot.
    return self;
}

-(void)addToQueue:(WebImage*)webimage{
    [self.queue addObject:webimage];
    if (!fetching){ //if this method is already running then just let it keep going
        [self loadImages];
    }
}
-(void)loadImages{
    fetching = YES;
    if (self.queue.count == 0){ //base case
        fetching = NO;
        return;
    }
    WebImage *webimage = [self.queue firstObject];
    [self.queue removeObject:webimage]; //move closer to the base case
    [self.conman getImageWithURL:webimage.image_URL inBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSString *error, id image) {
        if (image){
            webimage.image = image;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"error getting image %@, error: %@", webimage.image_URL, error);
            [self.queue addObject:webimage]; //add it to the end of the queue to try again later
        }
        [self loadImages];
    }];
}
```

and in other classes I just call:

```
[[ImageLoader defaultLoader] addToQueue:webImage];
```

EDIT: 
something is definitely being released. I don't know what the problem is but I changed the defaultLoader method to just return a pointer to an instance that the appdelegate holds which fixes the problem. Although I would still like to understand why what I have above isn't working.

```
+(ImageLoader*)defaultLoader{
    ImageLoader *loader = ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).imageLoader;
    if (!loader) loader = [[ImageLoader alloc] init];
    return loader;
  /*  
    static dispatch_once_t prede;
    static ImageLoader *sharedInstance = nil;
    dispatch_once(&prede, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[ImageLoader alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
   */
}
```

Comment: Your ImageLoader class is clearly not thread safe.

Comment: How would I make it thread safe?